# C++ - Array values in class member function changing spontaneously

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm having some issues overloading the *= operator in my polynomial class. I've included all I believed relevant to solving the problem below. I apologize for the length of the code.

Here are the parts of my class header I think are relevant.

```
#ifndef POL_H
#define POL_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Pol
{
  // private data members

  string polname;  // polynomial name
  int degree;      // polynomial degree
  int *coef;       // array with polynomial coefficients

 public:

  //  constructors

  Pol(string, int, int*);         // with input name, degree 
                                  // and array of coefficients
  // operator overloading

  Pol operator *= (Pol);

  //  other methods

  void PrintPol ();
```

Here is my .C file with the overload of *=. I decided not to include the PrintPol method as it is very long and I'm almost 100% sure the problem does not lie with it.

```
#include "Pol.h"

Pol::Pol (string s, int d, int *c)
{
  degree = d;
  polname = s;
  coef = new int [degree + 1];
  coef = c;

  // initializes polynomial of degree d with c coefficients
  // named s
}

Pol Pol::operator *= (Pol p1)
{
  int *cp = this->coef; // If I print the values stored in cp at this point 
                        // everything is alright

  for (int i = p1.degree; i >= 0; --i)
    {
      for (int j = this->degree; j >= 0; --j)
    {
      this->coef[i + j] += p1.coef[i] * cp[j];
      cout << cp[j] << endl; // When I print the values here, they've changed!
    }
    }

  this->degree += p1.degree;

  return *this;
}
```

My first thought was that maybe I was overstepping the bounds of the array, but the size of the array cp I create is this->degree, and that is also the highest value that "j" assumes, so I think that can't be it.

Here is just my main function. I doubt the problem is here, but I included it anyway, so you could see how I'm using the methods I've declared.

```
#include "Pol.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int a [9] = {0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1};
  int b [5] = {4, -2, 0, 0, 1};

  Pol P2 ("P2", 4, b);
  Pol P4 ("P4", 8, a);

  P4*= P2;
  P4.PrintPol();

  return 0;
}
```

This is probably really obvious and I'm just making an ass out of myself, but I've staring at the code for hours and I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I apologize for the length of the code."_ This usually means you haven't finished reducing it yet. Although in this case it's not *too* bad....

Comment: This is also broken: `coef = new int [degree + 1];  coef = c;`  . You allocate some memory and then immediately leak it. It seems you don't understand what a pointer does. A pointer *points to data which is somewhere else in memory*. It doesn't contain that data or anything. When you assign a pointer, it means to point it at a different location in memory. You still have to make sure you manage the data that you want to point at.

Comment: @Aditya: Why is that?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oops! My bad. I meant operator overloading

Comment: @Aditya: And why is operator overloading not available in `.C` files?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about overloading `*=`, yet the problem has nothing to do with `*=`. You say your array values are changing "spontaneously", yet you're clearly changing them yourself, right there in the code.

```
int *cp = this->coef; // "If I print the values stored in cp at this point 
                      // everything is alright"

for (int i = p1.degree; i >= 0; --i) {
   for (int j = this->degree; j >= 0; --j) {
      this->coef[i + j] += p1.coef[i] * cp[j]; // <-- Well, you changed them here mate
      cout << cp[j] << endl; // "When I print the values here, they've changed!"
   }
}
```

From the way you commented `coef`'s declaration:

```
int *coef;       // array with polynomial coefficients
```

it seems like you think `coef` is an array; it's not. You also seem to think that assigning `coef` to another `int*` will copy the underlying data that it points to; it will not.

**`coef` is a pointer, and assigning it to another pointer simply copies the pointer.**

Try using a `std::vector` like everybody else so that data ownership and lifetime is managed for you, and so that you may take advantage of the basic assignment operations.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. How I am changing the value of cp [j] in that line? Unless I'm completely wrong, the only thing i'm changing there is this->coef[i + j], no?

Comment: @user2949903: `cp` and `this->coef` are both pointers that point to the same data, because a few lines above it you wrote `int *cp = this->coef;` Nothing is stored "in `cp`". `cp` is a pointer. It is not an array. It does not contain data; it _points to data_. The same data as `this->coef` points to. Which C++ book are you using?